# Angular5: Build json from values

Tags: javascript, angular, ecmascript-6, lodash

I am trying to build a json from values so that I can push it to an object. 
I have two items as below.

```
var item1 = "2"
var item2 = "Student"
```

I am trying to build a json as below

```
{ "2" : "student"}
```

I tried couple of ways but ran out of ideas. Is there an easy way or any lodash method to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use ES6 computed properties like:

```
{ [item1]: item2 }
```

Answer (score 0):

create a Array temp variable and put them on it like this:

```
var item1 = "2"
var item2 = "Student"
  let tmp = [item1, item2];
  console.log(JSON.stringify(tmp));
```

after stringify result is :

```
["2","Student"]
```

or this on :

```
var student = "2";
console.log(JSON.stringify({student}));
```

result is:

```
{"student":"2"}
```